# Generating cryptographc random number for modulus of powers of 10 with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, random, cryptography

Using the crypto library I can require the library to give me a number of random bytes. The thing is that this bytes are numbers from 0 to 255 each (inclusive) and thus it is not that simple to create a uniformly distributed results.

What I mean is the following:

The function receives a number N, which is 10, 100, ... 10^b, where b is a number between 1 and 8 (could be bigger, but I don't need anything larger) and returns a number between 0 and the given number (not inclusive to the given number), so say if N is 100, the results of the function are from 0 to 99, and if N is 10 the results are from 0 to 9.

You can create a random number by using Math.random and just multiplying by N and then using floor. However, Math.random is not cryptographically safe, so it must be done by using randomly generated number that are of 2^8m, where m is just whatever number of bytes is given to crypto.randomBytes.

I created a simple function which is working, apparently. However, I am aware that it is fairly easy to induce some bias into random numbers and I would just like to have it validated, since it is somewhat important for the project.

```
genera_aleatorio_residuo_potencia10 : function (n, cb) {
  var digitos = Math.log(n) / Math.LN10;
  var extra_base2 = digitos > 8 ? digitos - 8 : 0;
  if (Math.floor(digitos + .4) - digitos > 0.00000001) {
    return cb("Numero no es potencia de 10 (10, 100, 1000...)", null);
  }
  digitos = Math.round(digitos);
  async.parallel({
    r1 : crypto_helper.generador_random_bytes(1),
    r2 : crypto_helper.generador_random_bytes(1)
  }, function (err, res) {
    if (err) {
      return cb(err, null);
    }
    var r1 = res.r1[0] + 1;
    var r2 = res.r2[0] + 1;
    var aleatorio = (Math.pow(5, digitos) - 1) * Math.pow(2, extra_base2) * r1 + r2;
    cb(null, aleatorio % n);
  });
}
```

Needless to say: crypto_helper.generador_random_bytes is a wrapper of node.js' crypto.randomBytes that I frequently use to make it friendlier with the async library.

My reasoning for using Math.pow(5, digitos) and the Math.pow(2, extra_base2) is for the least common multiple between N and 256. In practice, n will never be larger than 100000000, so the Math.pow(2, extra_base2) shouldn't be used in our product, but I would still like to be sure it makes sense to other people.

Comment: What is your end goal here? I love crypto problems and I'll totally sink my teeth into this one if I can understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I will describe it in a few minutes, I'm in a hurry at the moment. Thank you for your interest. And I found a bug in the formula used anyway, so I gotta update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a great solution by simply mimicking what Java's SecureRandom.nextInt(int) is doing at here: [SecureRandom.nextInt(int)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/security/SecureRandom.java#SecureRandom.next%28int%29) Will post code as soon as I can get to code it (I'm busy at the moment). I plan to use the code I develop from it, since I confirmed the proposed solution has a bias (it is not acceptable at all).

Here is the adaptation of the JDK code. Notice the limitations on 31 bit numbers, since I realized JS does all its bitwise operations on two's complement with 32 bits. 
I did not implement the special case for power of 2 numbers since I won't be using it. The solution is for numbers in general and not only powers of 10... I'm sure there must be a better solution for numbers with base 10, but whatever. I rewrote the code to not use my libraries and to make it in English, so that others can use it more easily.

```
var crypto_random_number_range = function (n, cb) {
  //result is a number from 0 a n-1
  //Javascript works with 32 bits for bitwise operations but these are signed (2-complement), so it is good to limit the size of n
  if (n <= 0 || n > 2147483647) {
    return cb("n must be larger than 0 and smaller than 2147483647", null);
  }
  var bits, val;
  async.doWhilst(
    function (cb2) {
      crypto.randomBytes(4, function (err, rbytes) {
        if (err) {
          return cb2(err);
        }
        bits = ((rbytes[3] & 0x7f) << 24) + 
          (rbytes[2] << 16) + (rbytes[1] << 8) + rbytes[0];
        val = bits % n;
        cb2();
      });
    }, function () {
      return (bits - val + (n-1)) < 0;
    }, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        return cb(err, null);
      }
      return cb(null, val);
    }
  );
}
```

Did several tests, it seems to be working just fine.

Comment: I programmed the same thing for Java Card, which worked fine as well. It is important to at least create tests for the distribution of the random numbers. Note that while this is a much better solution than just directly testing for the range - but it is not *optimal* (especially regarding numbers slightly above half the maximum, for which about half the loops will fail). Then again it is probably good enough and extremely fast and simple to program.

Comment: I did some tests on the distribution (and found a stupid bug I introduced while I rashly programmed it) and it seems to work beautifully. Indeed, the docs I found on the method estimate that the worst average case is 2 iterations. When doing tests I found it is behaving with most of the times doing only one iteration. Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: Yes, most of the time it is reliable for the first try, but if you have e.g. a single byte, value 0..255 and you request a number of 128 or slightly more, then it becomes less effective. This is normally only an issue if you have a very slow RNG, or if you need oodles of random numbers within a range (+1 of course)

Answer (score -3):

```
var kazutsukuru = function kazutsukuru(kaketeiruno, kotae) {
  crypto.randomBytes(4, function(mondai, baito) {
    if (mondai) {
      return kotae(mondai);
    }

    kotae(null, Math.floor(baito.readUInt32BE(0) / 4294967296 * kaketeiruno));
  });
};
```

This should do what you want. I decided to make my answer hard to read because your question is hard to read.